# JavaScript function for radio button input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

Currently i have made two radio buttons, one displays input fields one the other doesn't. How would i modify my java script function to show different input fields when the other radio button is clicked.

```
<tr>
  <td class="odd" width="20%" nowrap>
    <bean:message key="editvarref.header.name"/>
  </td>
  <td class="odd" width="80%">
    <div>
      <html:radio styleId="users_name_type_0" property="user_type" value="Show" onclick="getResults(this)" />
     <label for="user_name_type_0"><bean:message key="input.use.name"/> </label>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
    <html:radio styleId="email_name_type_1" property="user_type" value="Nothing" onclick="getResults(this)" />
    <label for="email_name_type_1"><bean:message key="input.use.email"/></label>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
      </p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

the js function im using is getResults():

```
function getResults(elem) {
        elem.checked && elem.value == "Show" ? $(".text").show() : $(".text").hide();
       };
```

I've tried using an if statement but i got an error and when i tried it using getElementById only the one button worked. How would I modify the JavaScript function to show another div

```
    <div class="email">
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" maxlength="30">
      </p>
    </div>
```

Do I also have to add a control statement in the reset function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You need to be way more specific than "an if statement" for people to understand what you've already tried.) But try changing your onclick function to this:

```
function getResults(elem){
  if (elem.value == "Show") {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".email").hide();
  } else {
    $(".email").show();
    $(".text").hide();        
  }
}
```